# sql query to search city,state and country like expedia.co.in

Tags: mysql, search, sql-like

I have a table with 4 columns

**id,city,state,country**

I want to search first city then state and then country.

I am using the following query but it does not seems to be working for me.

```
(SELECT * FROM `Destination_Detail` WHERE `city` like '%new york%') 
union  
(SELECT * FROM `Destination_Detail` WHERE `state` like '%new york%') 
union  
(SELECT * FROM `Destination_Detail` WHERE `country` like '%new york%')
```

I am using database of expedia and need to implement the same searching like [expedia](http://www.expedia.co.in/).

Firstly it is giving me duplicate entries.Also I think this is not th right way I am using to get the results there must be some efficient way.

Please help me to query it.

Thanks

Comment: You managed to write a *complex* `union` but didn't think about a *simple* `or` statement <g>. `select * from xx where city like '%xx%' or state like '%xx%' or ...`

Comment: no bro @LievenKeersmaekers I already thought for it but it can not do my job. Please look at expedia search it is totally different.e.g If I type search for new york then result should come first city new york then second record whatever with state new york. If I search india then result should come first of whatever city but country india as there is no city named india while there are already cities like indiana etc of some country. Hope you got me if not please make search on expedia.co.in

Comment: if sortorder is your problem, I would suggest to provide some test data and expected outputs. You can't expect anyone to go figure out how expedia does it and looking at the answers and comments, it currently isn't clear.

Answer (score 1):

```
select * FROM `Destination_Detail` 
where city like '%new york%'
   or state like '%new york%'
   or country like '%new york%'
order by city like '%new york%' desc, 
         state like '%new york%' desc, 
         country like '%new york%' desc
```

Comment: it will give me the result according to cities first but let's say i searched for India then on expedia it shows the result for india country first then anything else but here it is showing Indianapolis city first and so on and after cities states then it comes to country

Answer (score 0):

You can split your task into two different queries: one for finding the exact matches and one that will find the partial matches.

```
(SELECT * FROM places WHERE city = "india" OR state = "india" OR country = "india" ORDER BY city DESC, state DESC, country DESC)
UNION
(SELECT * FROM places WHERE city LIKE "%india%" OR state LIKE "%india%" OR country LIKE "%india%" ORDER BY city DESC, state DESC, country DESC)
```

If the user searched for "india", that would return places having India as their country first (supposing there are no places with their city or state name as India) and then the partially matched cities like Indianapolis, states like Indiana etc.

Improvement ideas: you could add a third query that would sort matches like "india%" before the matches like "%india%", giving preference to the partial matches where the beginning of the word is the same. That could also be achieved by sorting the partial matches by INSTR(column, "searchstring"), that would have the additional benefit of sorting matches where the substring occurs early before the ones where it occurs later ("abindia" would come before "abcindiana").

EDIT: Here are the queries I tested it with:

```
CREATE TABLE places(
  city VARCHAR(255),
  state VARCHAR(255),
  country VARCHAR(255)
);

INSERT INTO places(city, state, country) VALUES('New York', 'New York', 'USA');
INSERT INTO places(city, state, country) VALUES('Manhattan', 'New York', 'USA');
INSERT INTO places(city, state, country) VALUES('Niagara Falls', 'New York', 'USA');

INSERT INTO places(city, state, country) VALUES('Delhi', '', 'India');
INSERT INTO places(city, state, country) VALUES('Mumbai', '', 'India');
INSERT INTO places(city, state, country) VALUES('Indianapolis', 'Indiana', 'USA');
INSERT INTO places(city, state, country) VALUES('Fort Wayne', 'Indiana', 'USA');
```

Results for "New York":

```
CITY    STATE   COUNTRY
New York    New York    USA
Manhattan   New York    USA
Niagara Falls   New York    USA
```

Results for "India":

```
CITY    STATE   COUNTRY
Mumbai      India
Delhi       India
Indianapolis    Indiana USA
Fort Wayne  Indiana USA
```

I don't have the full database from expedia.co.in but to me it looks that at least the queries I ran returned the correct results. How are your results different?

Comment: no its not giving me the correct results. First I searched for india in that it gave me 4 india country results then 1 result fot state india of us and then again india country results. Then I searched for new york but in that case it is giving results for state new york first not cities at all. I am not getting what the smartness is used in expedia.co.in

Comment: I updated the post with the test data & queries I used.